# @Catch is giving "unexpected @" error in Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: ios, xcode, exception

Xcode is giving me an error `unexpected @` in program in my .m file.

Here's an example (with errors in comments)

```
@catch (NSException *excepton) {                 // unexpected '@'  in program
     self.userOutlet.text=@"exception error";
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter where I put the @catch statement in the code, I always get the error when building.

I've enabled `Enable C++ Exceptions` and `Enable Objective-C Exceptions`.

Is this something with Xcode 4.6.2 or is there another Build Setting I need to enable?

Comment: Is this coming after an `@try` block? Can you post a more complete code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown it, so I need to ask: you do have a `@try {...}` block defined above it don't you. You'll need to have one to pick up the `@catch`.

But generally with Cocoa, it's more usual to deal with errors using `NSError` rather than Exceptions which are mostly used for programmer errors.

Have a look at the [Exception Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

It look likes you want to use @catch without @try or you want to paste some code between these blocks and it is impossible